# Store file mapping from local to cloud

Tags: python, cloud

In Python, what do you believe is the best way to store file mapping info from local machine to cloud storage?

i.e. A user has 10 files in 3 different folders on his local machine. They are also stored on a cloud storage, each identify by URL or other descriptors.

Best way - in terms of scallability, search/insert efficiency, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use the [rsync program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync), or the [rsync algorithm](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577518-rsync-algorithm/) implemented in Python. Assumably you can have access to the remote files over something that looks like a file system, like WebDAV.

Best

Comment: Thanks, but what I meant was how to store the metadata of the files, and not how to sync the data itself